# Search query containing "base64" makes Wordpress blank page

Tags: wordpress

Very strange.

works fine:
https://helloacm.com/?s=kasdjfaksjdf

but if any query containing "base64", the page is empty

https://helloacm.com/?s=kasdjfaksjdfbase64

I have installed the latest WP version is 4.3 billie and I just CloudFlare.

not just one of the website, my other domain have the same thing:

https://codingforspeed.com/?s=base64

https://justyy.com/?s=base64

Comment: If it's your site try to enable debug in `wp-config.php`

Comment: This seems to be directly related to the theme/plugins your using. It also feels like a hole in security. What theme is it you are using?

Comment: I am using Twenty-Twelve the latest version 1.8

Comment: Just checked on few WP websites, can't replicate this behaviour. This must have to do with some plugin you're using.

Comment: @DoctorLai Then it must be down to a plugin, since this isn't reproducible using Twenty-Twelve. Disable them one-by-one checking your front-end each time.

Comment: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 414 (Request-URI Too Long)`

Comment: Have you looked in your apache error logs?

Comment: More on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719333/request-uri-too-large-414

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions.
I disabled the plugin one by one and find out it is the problem of "iThemes Security"

will raise this to their support.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/

find out that unticking the following option in the plugin solves the problem

Filter Long URL Strings
Limits the number of characters that can be sent in the URL. Hackers often take advantage of long URLs to try to inject information into your database.

Comment: thanks. unticking "Filter Long URL Strings" in "iThemes Security" solves the problem